# Anti-Aliasing with Pixel-by-Pixel filter

Tags: python, antialiasing

I've looked around on SO for a while for anti-aliasing algorithms that might work, but they all produce blurry images and/or aren't applicable to my current method.

I've created a pixel-by-pixel filter with Python and PIL that creates a palette of colors (how they're determined isn't important.) The code creates an image like the one below. As you can see, it's very aliased.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUETH.png

I've heard that the best way to anti-alias an image is to do it while the image is being drawn, not afterwards; however, I'm not sure if this is possible with my current method, which is to loop through each individual pixel. If a method by which I can anti-alias the image while it is being drawn is possible, please post it here.

Here's the code:

```
import Image, ImageDraw
from collections import Counter

def avg_color(arr):
    r,g,b = 0,0,0
    for item in arr:
        r += item[0]
        g += item[1]
        b += item[2]
    l = len(arr)
    return (r//l,g//l,b//l)

COLOR_NUMBER = 12

PATH = "test.png"

COLORS = [
(255,255,255),
(0,0,0)
]

im = Image.open(PATH)
rgbim = im.convert('RGB')

size = rgbim.size

nim = Image.new('RGB', size)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(nim)

for i in range(COLOR_NUMBER-2):
    devs = [[765 for j in range(size[1])] for k in range(size[0])]
    cols = [[765 for j in range(size[1])] for k in range(size[0])]
    ind = []
    for x in range(size[0]):
        for y in range(size[1]):
            r,g,b = rgbim.getpixel((x,y))
            cols[x][y] = (r,g,b)
            for c in COLORS:
                diff = abs(c[0]-r)+abs(c[1]-g)+abs(c[2]-b)
                devs[x][y] = min(diff,devs[x][y])

    h = (0,0)
    for x in range(size[0]):
        for y in range(size[1]):
            if devs[x][y] > devs[h[0]][h[1]]:
                h = (x,y)
    print "Added color",cols[h[0]][h[1]]
    COLORS.append(cols[h[0]][h[1]])



print("Created palette.")
print(COLORS)

for x in range(size[0]):
    for y in range(size[1]):
        r,g,b = rgbim.getpixel((x,y))
        devarray = []
        col = COLORS[0]
        for c in COLORS:
            diff = abs(c[0]-r)+abs(c[1]-g)+abs(c[2]-b)
            devarray.append(diff)
        smallest = 0
        for i in range(len(devarray)):
            if devarray[i] < devarray[smallest]:
                smallest = i
        col = COLORS[smallest]
        draw.point((x,y),fill=col)

print "Finished rough image."


nim.show()
```

Comment: Anti-aliasing can be done by pixel adding up pixel sub-samples. You can fake it by doubling the pixels in the original image, applying your filter. and then halving the dimensions. The color of the each final pixel in the last step could be a simple average of the each the group of corresponding four being replaced.

Comment: @martineau, the problem is that I am taking an input image and adding pixel transformations. So each of the four pixels would be exactly the same, resulting in more memory usage and no antialiasing.